# Passing optional argument in any order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn some new trick with my python code using *args and **kwargs.
When calling my program, I want to pass or not two optional parameters which can come in any order. Obviously if no argument are given during the call, the variable should get some default value.

in my usual code I would have something like this if i know the exact place of each parameters and that all parameters must be given:

```
import sys
var1 = 10 if len(sys.argv) == 1 else (sys.argv[1])
debug= False if len(sys.argv) < 3 else (sys.argv[2])
```

but this time, since i want to be able to give any of the two parameters and in any order, i am getting stuck at how i should write it.
When doing:

- `python mycode.py` i want to have `var1 = 10` and `debug=False`
- `python mycode.py var1=4.3` i want to have `var1 = 4.3` and `debug=False`
- `python mycode.py debug='True'` i want to have `var1 = 10` and `debug=True`
- `python mycode.py var1=-5 debug='True'` i want to have `var1 = -5` and `debug=True`
- `python mycode.py debug='True' var1=-5` i want to have `var1 = -5` and `debug=True`

last thing, is there also a way that user can call using `debug=true` with all small letter and not triggering an error message?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Not sure exactly how your code works, but you could make a variable called `true` whose value is `True`

Comment: You need to parse command-line arguments being passed to your script. You can do it manually from `sys.args` or by using the `argparse` module.

Comment: var1 = kwargs["var1"] if "var1" in kwargs else 10

Answer (score 2):

`*args` and `**kwargs` refer to arguments for functions. Read about it in the docs: [More on Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions)

For **command-line arguments**, have a look at the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#command-line-arguments) again:

> Common utility scripts often need to process command line arguments.
>   These arguments are stored in the `sys` module’s *argv* attribute as a list. For instance the following output results from running `python demo.py one two three` at the command line:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.argv)
['demo.py', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

> [...] More powerful and flexible command line processing is provided by the `argparse` module.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) for `argparse`

[Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#id1) for `argparse`

Comment: Great, i think with this argparse, i'll probably manage to do what i want this time.